# Ayuda con un codigo en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net

espero que me puedan ayudar con el siguiente codigo que tengo en visual studio, estoy programando un login de usuarios, en asp.net con c# y resulta que en mi formulario aspx llamado **PortalAlumons.aspx.cs** escribí el siguiente codigo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectSQL"].ToString());
        SqlCon.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM sisacad.USUARIO WHERE Rut_Nro = '"+Txt_RutNro.Text+"' AND Rut_Dig = ' "+Txt_RutDigito.Text+" ' AND Contrasena = ' "+Txt_Pass.Text+" '  ";

        SqlCommand cMD = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);

        string output = cMD.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); //ESTA LINEA ME ARROJA EL ERROR

        if (output == "1")
        {
            Session["user"] = Txt_RutNro.Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/Alumno.aspx");
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("Conexion Fallida");
        }
    }
```

Resulta que el error que me arroja dice lo siguiente:

> **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.**
>
> **Descripción:** Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. 
>   Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del 
>   error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> **Detalles de la excepción:** System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto 
>   no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>
> **Error de código fuente:**
>
> *Línea 23:*
>
> *Línea 24:*             *SqlCommand cMD = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);*
>
> *Línea 25:*            *string output = cMD.ExecuteScalar().ToString();*
>
> *Línea 26:*
>
> *Línea 27:*             *if (output == "1")*

Esto me pasa cuando hago clic en un enlace que me redirecciona a la pagina del portal de los alumnos, donde el alumno podra iniciar sesion y posteriormente ingresar a su web personal de estudios. Y la linea del error es la 25.

Si me pudieran ayudar estaria muy agradecido, gracias.

Comment: el método `cMD.ExecuteScalar();` está retornando `null` , haga la verificación correspondiente antes de acceder al método `toString();`

Comment: revisa tu query, estas haciendo un "SELECT * ", estas consultando todos los registros de la tabla y luego abajo pretendes tratarlo como un escalar..

Comment: te recomiendo que en la consulta no busques por select *, sino por select count(0), de este modo si existe el resultado sera 1 y sino 0, asi nunca sera null.

Comment: Este sitio apesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo bastantes problemas en tu código.

El error se está produciendo por que `cMD.ExecuteScalar()` está devolviendo `null`. `ExecuteScalar` se utiliza normalmente cuando una consulta devuelve un único dato en lugar de un conjunto de registros, normalmente cuando se realiza una consulta con una función de agregado sin `GROUP BY`.

Si, como en tu caso, lo aplicas a una consulta que va a devolver datos de diferentes campos, lo que hará será devolver el valor del primer campo del primer registro, o `null` si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado.

Es decir, si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia el resultado no será `0` si no `null`.

Por otro lado tu código es un ejemplo claro de código vulnerable a un ataque por Sql Injection (te recomendaría buscar un poco sobre el tema por internet). Para evitar esto, y por otras razones como claridad de código o rendimiento, deberías acostumbrarte a construir siempre tus consultas introduciendo los valores a través de parámetros.

Échale un vistazo a este ejemplo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectSQL"].ToString());
    SqlCon.Open();

    string query =
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sisacad.USUARIO WHERE Rut_Nro=@RutNro AND Rut_Dig=@RutDig AND Contrasena=@Pass";
    SqlCommand cMD = new SqlCommand(query, SqlCon);
    cMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutNro", Txt_RutNro.Text);
    cMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutDig", Txt_RutDigito.Text);
    cMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", Txt_Pass.Text);

    int output = (int)cMD.ExecuteScalar();

    if (output>0)
    {
        Session["user"] = Txt_RutNro.Text;
        Response.Redirect(@"~/Alumno.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Conexion Fallida");
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pude resolver mi error, Asier Villanueva